# Asp.Net 4.0 WebSite Form Authentication to Asp.Net WebApi Cookiess not passing

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, form-authentication

I ran into an issue during Asp.net WebApi calls from client side.

WHAT I HAVE DONE

my asp.net 4.0 website form authentication set in the configuration as below

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".XXXXXXX" protection="All" path="/" timeout="20" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="false" ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40"  />
    </authentication>
```

and the above is also se in the Asp.Net4.5MVC4 WebApi project (Hosted on IIS 7).

WHAT IAM FACING.

I login to my website OK.
I directly access the WebApi from the URL (Works OK with Above Authentication) and data Shown OK.

BUT

When i call the webapi url from the client site as below

```
$.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: type,
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function (data) {
              if (typeof (callbackSuccess) === 'function') {
                callbackSuccess(data);
            }
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
               if (typeof (failCallback) === 'function') {
                    failCallback(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
        }).always(function () { //something});
```

> The above calls behind the button works like a charm in IE10 and
>   cookies goes A OK.

BUT in FireFox (latest) There is no success as well as in the Chrome in data retrival as it always goes to the $.ajax fail call.

---

As the Response Url from WebApi `(localhost:xxx/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fapi%2fApiController%2fGet%2f)`

---

Any one have any idea what i have ran INTO and How to Get out.

As i am making  a GET and POST calls

NOTE: Do let me know if some this is missing from the question asked. :)

Comment: Any Suggetions plz
I have also included these in the webapi project config
'<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Method" value="GET,POST,PUT" />'
No luck :)